# Docker-compose: указать папку для установки пакета из образа

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть ли какая-либо команда в Docker-compose которая позволяет указать папку для установки образа. При использовании команды "build" требуется, чтобы в данной папке был Dockerfile.

*Я хочу указать путь для установки, но Dcokerfile я вообще не планирую использовать, я хочу просто указать параметр "image".*

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.14
    build:
      !!! context: ./docker/mysql !!!
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=xxx
      - MYSQL_USER=xxx
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxx
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 1):

в Docker-compose можно указать следующим образом

```
... 
build:
  context: . //вот тут путь к папке с Dockerfile
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate // а тут название файла

...
больше информации [тут](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)
```

если билдите с помощью docker, то можно использовать флаг `-f`

```
docker build -f dockerfiles/Dockerfile.debug -t myapp_debug .
```

подробнее [тут](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

Comment: Есть ли вариант при котором можно не использовать Dockerfile? Я хочу указать путь для установки, но Dcokerfile я вообще не планирую использовать, я хочу просто указать параметр "image".

Comment: images выгружаются в специальном месте для докера. доступны только через докер. можно выгрузить image так `docker export myImage > myImageName.tar`
 `

Comment: Привел пример того, что мне нужно в теле вопроса. Я пытаюсь сделать только одно: используя **только** docker-compose развернуть контейнер и указать ему путь для установки. (Важное условие: **не используя Dockerfile**).